# git merge file with conflict

Tags: git, bitbucket

Aaron and Billy are working on the same file (abcd.text) on master. Aaron committed the file first. When Billy do git pull, he has a conflict. How can Billy take in the changes from Aaron and still keep his own changes? What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you asking us to answer your homework question for you?

Comment: What does "best" here even mean? There are ways of handling conflicts, and they depend on the code, the tools you have, and the type of conflicts. Billy should go examine the conflicts and if needed talk with Aaron.

Answer (score 0):

To get the changes with [rebasing local changes]

> git pull --rebase

This can result in conflict and those **needs to be manually resolved**. [Reference](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line).

After resolving

> git add resolved_files

Rebasing is not complete due to conflicts, now continue the rebase

> git rebase --continue

This should solve your issue. There are of course many different ways to acheive the same but I feel this is the simplest.